# Items overflowing out of my div

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have tabs that contain a users post, After a second status is posted everything just falls out of the tab content area making the page look really bad.

Here is the code I'm having an error with dashboard.html.erb,

```
<ul class="tabs">
                            <li>
                                <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
                                <label for="tab1">Profile</label>
                                    <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default-blue">  
                                        <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i> <p class="status">Status</p> 
                                                <p class="divider-for-status">|</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "What's new?" %>
                                            </div>
                                            <p> 
                                                <%= f.submit %>
                                            </p>

                                        <% end %>
                                        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading-gray"> <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %> <h5 class="user-name"><%= @user.name %></h5> <h6 class="time-posted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></h6>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body"><%= link_to post.body, post %></div>
                                                        <div class="panel-footer"> 
                                                        <h5>Add a comment:</h5>                                     <p class="Like-option">Like ·</p>
                                                            <p class="comment-form">Comment - </p>  
                                                            <p class="view-option">· View</p>
                                                            <p class="comment-profile-picture">
                                                            <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <div class="comments-stream">


                                                            </div>

                                                            <div id="comments-form">

                                                            </div>  
                                                        </div> 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                     </div>
                            </li>
```

And here is the css for these dashboard.css.scss,

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
          position: absolute;
          top: -9999px;
          left: -9999px;
      }
      .tabs {
        width: 650px;
        float: none;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 12px auto;
        box-shadow: 1.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      .tabs li{
        float: left;
      }
      .tabs label:hover {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        top: 0;
      }
      .tabs label {
          display: block;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
          color: #08C;
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-family: 'Lily Script One', helveti;
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
          top: 3px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }


       [id^=tab]:checked + label {
        background: #08C;
        color: white;
        top: 0;
      }

      [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
          display: block;
      }


.tab-content-1 {
        z-index: 2;
        display: none;
        text-align: left;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 140%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background: white;
        padding: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 53px;
        left: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        box-shadow: 1.5px 1px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin-top: -12px;
      }
```

I will post any other code you may need to see or even anymore details, I appreciate any help!

Comment: It might be helpful to post a live demo / jsfiddle of the problem, so people will be able to readily see what's wrong. Also, Stack Overflow is generally kind of quiet on Sundays, so getting some answers might just be a matter of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

There were several formatting errors.  This code corrects those.  I didn't try it beyond that question.

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
    <label for="tab1">Profile</label>

    <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      <div class="panel panel-default-blue">
        <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>

              <p class="status">Status</p>

              <p class="divider-for-status">|</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "What's new?" %>
            </div>
            <p>
              <%= f.submit %>
            </p>

        <% end %>
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading-gray"> <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %>
                <h5 class="user-name"><%= @user.name %></h5>
                <h6 class="time-posted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body"><%= link_to post.body, post %></div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <h5>Add a comment:</h5>

                <p class="Like-option">Like ·</p>

                <p class="comment-form">Comment - </p>

                <p class="view-option">· View</p>

                <p class="comment-profile-picture">
                  <%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.url(:thumb) %>
                </p>

                <div class="comments-stream">


                </div>

                <div id="comments-form">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```